# Is there a problem using resize2fs too often?

Tags: ext3, resize2fs

I have a partition which contains MySQL data which is constantly growing. My LVM PV has precious little free space remaining and therefore I find I'm frequently adding additional space to my `/var` partition using `lvextend` and `resize2fs` in smallish increments (250-500 MB at a time) so as not to give too much space to `/var` and then be unable to allocate those PEs to other partitions should I need to later.

I'm concerned about reaching some limit or causing a problem by calling `resize2fs` too often to grow this filesystem. Is there a limit to how often `resize2fs` can be used to grow an Ext3 filesystem? Is it better to do one large Ext3 resize rather than many small ones? Does resizing using `resize2fs` too often carry a potential for problems or data loss?

Comment: None that I've ever seen/heard of.

Comment: Same here @sim but I get worried that resizing my company's MySQL filesystem might cause data loss... yet RAID10 space is very expensive and difficult to expend, so...

Comment: Highly opinionated, but there have been a few bugs with `resize2fs`, including one that could render the filesystem unresizeable. If you already know that you'll have to `resize2fs` again soon anyway, I'd not do it in minor steps. More free space at once also helps avoid unnecessary fragmentation, and helps performance in other ways, so there are side effects to consider as well.

Comment: Fragmentation isn't exactly an area of concern because this particular server is already heavily virtualized and it's a RAID10 infrastructure. So I'm not too concerned about that. Also, it's the InnoDB tables that are growing for the most part. But a bug that renders the filesystem unresizable is pretty nasty @frostschutz!

Comment: [This article](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/increase_the_size_of_an_ext2_ext3_or_ext4_filesystem.html) notes that you can end up with a less optimal block size if you gradually but significantly increase a filesystem size. Doesn't sounds like a key problem for you, depending on how long you're going to be doing it for :) ps. I sympathise - I'm also coping with InnoDB growth.

Comment: Specifically it says, *Note that resize2fs does not change the block size, even if a freshly created filesystem on the same device would default to a larger size. For this reason, recreation may be a better option if you need to turn a very small filesystem into a very large one.* so it's not so much about using `resize2fs` too often, it's about making a small filesystem large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond the wear and tear on the HDDs I can't see any reason why this would be dangerous. I've never come across a EXT3/EXT4 parameter that limits the amount of times you can do this. There isn't any counter I've seen either.

In looking through the output from `tune2fs` I see nothing that I would find alarming which would lead me to believe that performing many resizes would be harmful to the filesystem or the device, beyond the wear and tear.

#### Example

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root
tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          74e66905-d09a-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
Filesystem magic number:  0x1234
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              3276800
Block count:              13107200
Reserved block count:     655360
Free blocks:              5842058
Free inodes:              2651019
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1020
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Sat Dec 18 19:05:48 2010
Last mount time:          Mon Dec  2 09:15:34 2013
Last write time:          Thu Nov 21 01:06:03 2013
Mount count:              4
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Nov 21 01:06:03 2013
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          930 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       1973835
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      74e66905-d09a-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

#### dumpe2fs

You can also poke at the EXT3/EXT4 filesystems using `dumpe2fs` which essentially shows the same info as `tune2fs`. The output from that command is too much to include here, mainly because it includes information about the groups of inodes within the filesystem. But when I went through the output, again I saw no mention of any counters that were inherent within the EXT3/EXT4 filesystems.